# A question on terminology (Group Theory)

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, terminology

Is there a standard adjective to describe a finite group $G$ of composite order which possesses, for each (positive) divisor $d$ of $|G|$, a subgroup of order $d$?

I would guess "Lagrangian" but I can only seem to get one hit in the literature.

Many thanks!

JTE

Answer (score 3):

Such is called a CLT group (it stands for Converse of Lagrange's Theorem).

We do know supersolvable groups $\subset$ CLT groups $\subset$ solvable groups, both strictly.

Comment: So *that's* what CLT stands for.  I've wondered about that in the past.

Answer (score 3):

You are referring to so-called CLT groups.  You might find [this paper](http://msp.org/pjm/1968/27-2/pjm-v27-n2-p02-p.pdf) interesting.